Who should control the bitcoin discussion?
The bitcoin forum was recently hacked and the forum will now be hosted by Tibanne, a japanese company and owner of the largest bitcoin exchange. Is it better for a third party such as stack exchange to host bitcoin discussions or for a bitcoin company to do so ? I feel this is also related to the discussion about the domain for bitcoin.stackexchange.com as bitcointalk.com would be a great choice for that.
See the discussion at https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25/what-should-our-domain-name-be

The domain name question you refer to was closed, see the comments there. We will most likely simply use http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com.

I've read this question three times and I still can't figure out what it's asking. Are you asking for SE to host a Bitcoin discussion site? That's just not what SE does -- why would they do it for Bitcoin?

The existence of Bitcoin.SE should be independent of whether or not there are Bitcoin discussion forums out there.  For one thing, Bitcoin.SE is not a discussion forum (it is a Q&A site).  Furthermore, there is no "official" Bitcoin organization that this SE would even be competing with.
